# Dynamically updating the title component for a Material UI Tooltip

Tags: tooltip, material-ui

I am using a React Material UI Tooltip component.  Specifically :

```
render() {
    const {comment} = this.props;
    ...
    <Tooltip title={this.handleFlaggedComment(comment)}>
        <IconButton className={classes.tooltipIconButton} aria-label="Reported" href="">
            <ReportedIcon className={classes.reportedIcon} />
        </IconButton>
    </Tooltip>
    ...
}
```

The handleFlaggedComment is implemented as :

```
handleFlaggedComment = (comment) => {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <div>
           REPORTED COUNT&nbsp;:&nbsp;{comment.reportedCount}
        </div>
      </Fragment>
   )
}
```

Lets also assume there is a mapStateToProps which is implemented as :

```
mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        comment: state.commentsList.currentComment
    }
}
```

When the reportedCount goes from 1 to say 3, and I hover over the icon to show the tooltip, I would expect it to show 3 as the reportedCount. However it only shows 1 , which was the initial value

Is there a way to make the tooltip title update and show the updated comment, specifically the correct reportedCount ?

let us also assume that some UI action is triggering the reportedCount to increase. An example, is clicking on an icon that increments the reportedCount by 1 and it is updating state in redux for 'currentComment'

Comment: please post some more code. where is the variable comment coming from? how you increment reportedCount?

Comment: Updated code snippets,  hope this clarifies. If not, please let me know and I can cut and paste more code

Comment: are you sure comment is updated? if you console.log(comment) inside render, do you see the updated value?

Comment: hi, yes the comment is updated because some other comment updates the comment, and i see the comment that I need to pass in to the tooltip.  The comment has field for reportedCount.  I think there is a fundamental question here... Once you set the title component for the tooltip, can it be updated ?    I placed a breakpoint in handleFlaggedComment and did not see it being invoked again.  This leads to another question, is a Tooltip the right component to use for such an use case. I am going to experiment with Popper tomorrow

Comment: The tooltip can be changed after the props changes. There has to be something else wrong with your code. https://np3hm.csb.app/ . If handleFlaggedComment  is not called, there may be your problem that the component is not rerended correctly. Did you update commentsList currentComment immutable?